# Preselecting values from a multiple-select Rails form using select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I'm trying to get values pre-selected in a multi-select Rails 4 form that uses select2.

The entry looks like:

```
- bol_selected = segments.map { |bol| seg = Bol.find_by(id: bol.to_i); [seg.bl_number, seg.id] }
= f.select :bol, options_for_select(bol_selected, bol_selected), {}, multiple: true, size: 10, id: 'bol-multiple', class: 'form-control'
```

It is my understanding that `options_for_select` takes a list of options and values as its first parameter and the pre-selected options as its second parameter, which is exactly what I have above.

I am trying this along with the following js code:

```
$('#bol-multiple').select2({
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  allowClear: true,
  dropdownParent: $('#bol-multiple').parent(),
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  ajax: {
    url: '/autocomplete/bols.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(term, page) {
      return {
        q: term
      };
    }
  }
});
```

The HTML this generates is as follows:

```
<select multiple="" id="bol-multiple" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" name="cargo[bol_segments][]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
  <option value="25285">ZZMUM58</option>
</select>
```

as per some other SO threads I've also tried adding

```
data: [{id: 123, text: 'Some text'}]
```

to the above JavaScript but this doesn't seem to pre-select any entries, it only pre-populates multi-select dropdown with some values.

Just to make it clear - the AJAX call works fine and selecting multiple values also works fine. All I'm trying to do now is get certain values pre-selected in the input field.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your *HTML* of the select looks like in the console? Can you post it?

Comment: @Pavan sure thing, I've updated the post. I've noticed that Rails doesn't add `selected="selected"` to the `option` tag although I think I'm passing in the pre-selected values correctly.

Comment: can you try changing it to `= f.select :bol, options_for_select({bol_selected}, {bol_selected}), {}, multiple: true, size: 10, id: 'bol-multiple', class: 'form-control'`?

Comment: That causes a `syntax error, unexpected '}',`

Comment: Does this work `= f.select :bol, options_for_select(bol_selected, selected: bol_selected), {}, multiple: true, size: 10, id: 'bol-multiple', class: 'form-control'`

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Ok, last one. Try this `= f.select :bol, options_for_select({bol_selected}, bol_selected), {}, multiple: true, size: 10, id: 'bol-multiple', class: 'form-control'`

Comment: For `bol_selected`, I'm trying to pass in ID and text (`[['id1', 'text1'], ['id2', 'text2']]`) as well as id + text for the first param and just text for the second param, or id + text for the first param and just ids for the second param. Nothing seems to work

Comment: @Pavan thanks for the persistence :) no that also gives me `syntax error, unexpected '}'` unfortunately. I feel like the helper methods for select boxes are quite terrible in Rails

Comment: For the selected, the argument list should be the values, so try passing only ids as an array.

Comment: @Pavan I've just tried editing the HTML directly with developer tools and setting `multiple="true"` on the select tag and `selected="selected"` to the first option, but select2 doesn't seem to pre-select the option regardless. Might be an issue with select2

Comment: @Pavan ughhh that was it!! Thank you so much. I thought I'd passed in the IDs array as second param but I had only tried using values or values+id pair, not ids alone. It's quite a fragile system. Thanks for the help and persistence!

Comment: Glad that worked! :)